# How to disable all job-related interface elements?

Tags: support, user-interface, advertising, jobs, userscript

It is possible to somehow disable all the Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow interface elements on job search, developer story, etc.?

I only come here for the questions, but for anything else and it feels completely out of place for me. Stack Exchange would honestly not at all be the place I would look for this kind of content anyway.

Comment: It's one way of how they earn money, so this request has probably to go the way of the user script ;)

Comment: Just curious, why would you not expect / look for job related content on Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow? I'm sincerely just looking for feedback there, I'm writing an answer to your question now.

Comment: @TimPost I not the OP, but I feel the same way. I'm a hobbyist, with very little schooling. I've always used SO for QA, and never even noticed the job aspects until lately. Since there's 0 chance I'll ever find a job here, it *would* be nice to get rid of the job ads. If it supplies money for my favourite site though, I can put up with it. I've never really though about how you guys get money.

Comment: @TimPost The thing with job searches, like with any other feature, is relevance. To me, the Stack Exchange network is a source for answers to questions. It's very good at that, but if the question I'm looking to answer never is "Where can I get a job?", then any *non-ad* UI element that tells me it could answer that question is a needless distraction to my research.

Comment: A similar request on Meta SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373872/8828658

Answer (score 13):

Jobs is one of the primary ways that we pay our server bill and folks that work here, so it's *extremely* unlikely that we'll design a feature to allow users to hide that stuff. We currently offer reduced advertising to anyone with over 200 rep which moves all distractions to the sidebar (jobs stuff included), but we don't offer a way to turn it off completely.

If you want to do this, you'll need to write or make use of a browser extension or user script that hides those specific parts of the page, and we don't offer any official support on how to accomplish that.

However, if you have 200+ rep on a site and everything is confined to the sidebar, it wouldn't be that hard. I can't speak to the efficacy of existing ad blockers for the same purpose because I haven't used them.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use this userscript:

## [Stack Overflow Extras](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/29559)

> The SOX userscript adds a bunch of optional features to all sites in the Stack Exchange network. These can be toggled on or off from an easy to use control panel.

[image: enter link description here]